# Java + Apache Spark inner join between two datesets

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Small question regarding how to achieve inner join using Apache Spark and Java please.

I have this very simple piece of code.

```java
final Dataset<Row> dataSetTableLeft = getDatasetForLeft();
final Dataset<Row> dataSetTableRight = getDatasetForRight();
final Dataset<Row> dataSetTableResult = dataSetTableLeft.join(dataSetTableRight);

dataSetTableLeft.show();
dataSetTableRight.show();
dataSetTableResult.show();
```

The first table `dataSetTableLeft.show` , looks like this, very straightforward.

```
+----------+-----+
|      time|label|
+----------+-----+
|1637020800|    0|
|1637107200|    0|
|1637193600|    0|
|1637280000|    0|
|1637366400|    0|
|1637452800|    0|
+----------+-----+"
```

The second table `dataSetTableRight`, looks like this, also very straightforward.

```
+----------+-----+
|      time|label|
+----------+-----+
|1637193600|    1|
|1637280000|    2|
|1637366400|    1|
+----------+-----+"
```

What I would like to achieve is a result table like this, which is a kind of inner join.

```
+----------+-----+
|      time|label|
+----------+-----+
|1637020800|    0|
|1637107200|    0|
|1637193600|    1|
|1637280000|    2|
|1637366400|    1|
|1637452800|    0|
+----------+-----+"
```

Unfortunately, I am not seeing any function like this. `innerjoin()`

Therefore, I am trying some kind of combinations

```
dataSetTableLeft.unionAll(dataSetTableRight);
dataSetTableLeft.crossJoin(dataSetTableRight);
```

without any luck so far.

What is the correct way to achieve the inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join will only give you rows that exist in the two datasets. What you want here is to keep all rows from the `dataSetTableLeft` and retrieve `label` value from `dataSetTableRight` when `time` matches.

For this, simply use left join and [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) function to get `label` value from the second dataset when there is a match.

Here's complete working example with the provided data:

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

dataSetTableLeft.show();
//+----------+-----+
//|      time|label|
//+----------+-----+
//|1637020800|    0|
//|1637107200|    0|
//|1637193600|    0|
//|1637280000|    0|
//|1637366400|    0|
//|1637452800|    0|
//+----------+-----+

dataSetTableRight.show();
//+----------+-----+
//|      time|label|
//+----------+-----+
//|1637193600|    1|
//|1637280000|    2|
//|1637366400|    1|
//+----------+-----+


dataSetTableLeft.alias("df1").join(
        dataSetTableRight.alias("df2"),
        dataSetTableLeft.col("time").equalTo(dataSetTableRight.col("time")),
        "left_outer"
).select(
        dataSetTableLeft.col("time"),
        expr("coalesce(df2.label, df1.label)").alias("label")
).show();

//+----------+-----+
//|      time|label|
//+----------+-----+
//|1637020800|    0|
//|1637107200|    0|
//|1637193600|    1|
//|1637280000|    2|
//|1637366400|    1|
//|1637452800|    0|
//+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Hello @blackbishop, thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried your snippet, and it is yielding another result. the result is all the keys from column time, with the value 2, then the value 1. 1637020800 2 - 1637020800 1 - 1637107200 2 - 1637107200 1 - 1637193600 2 - 1637193600 1 etc. May I ask what did I do wrong please?

Comment: @PatPatPat Hello, not sure I understand your issue. I added a complete example using the provided data in your question. Please see my edited question.

Comment: With the new snippet, I could get the desired result. Thank you for laying out all the snippet, it is very helpful. This is the correct solution, upvote + accept. Good day!